# OracleDataReader not returning expected value

Tags: c#, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

When running a query through Oracle SQL Developer, a column's value is returned as such: "? some string value" (notice the leading '?')

However when the same query is run (from a c# program) and results processed using the OracleDataReader the column's value shows up as an empty string (not null).

Does '?' have a special meaning in this case?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Special meaning? I don't think so. I'm not aware of any default special processing that sqldeveloper applies to null values. But it will be easier to answer your "not expected value" question if you provide the query, the DDL, and some sample data.

Comment: The data reader should return exactly what is stored in the database. Something else is going on. Please provide more information, primarily your query.

Comment: Sorry, this had to do with setting the InitialLONGFetchSize different than the  default 0.  When I set it to -1 it works as expected.